# Can you have multiple labels for a vertex in Gremlin Tinkerpop like we do in Neo4J graph?

Tags: graph, label, gremlin

Neo4J allows multiple labels for the same node. This is very convenient. Do we have the same ability in Gremlin Tinkerpop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TinkerPop model does not allow for multiple labels as Neo4j does. It does however offer some specific support particularly for Neo4j ([documentation](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_multi_label)):

```
gremlin> vertex = (Neo4jVertex) g.addV('human::animal').next() 
==>v[0]
gremlin> vertex.label() 
==>animal::human
gremlin> vertex.labels() 
==>animal
==>human
gremlin> vertex.addLabel('organism')
==>null
gremlin> g.V().has(label,of('organism'))
==>v[0]
```

Comment: You can also have multiple labels on vertices in Amazon Neptune.

Comment: Thanks Stephen Mallett

Comment: Thanks bechbd. I will try that.